# How can I set a scroll bar on my Flex Application?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, window, scroll, policy

My Flex application is half cut off with no scroll bar in the browser window. How can I get a scroll bar? The application tag doesn't have a setVerticalScrollPollicy property.

Answer (score 0):

You need `verticalScrollPolicy` property (set it on/off/auto)

Comment: The application tag does not hold this property. Do I need to set it in the <s:layout> tags?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use scroller. Please refer [this](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex4_viewport_scrolling.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_2) link to learn more about scrollers in Flex4.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a  to the main application's SKIN file around the contentGroup. Answered here: [Flex ScrollBars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345234/flex-scrollbars)